# C99 definition of "processor time"

Tags: c, language-lawyer, c99

Section 7.23.1 paragraph 1 of the C99 standard defines several "time" terms:

> Many functions deal with a *calendar time* that represents the current
>   date (according to the Gregorian calendar) and time. Some functions deal with *local
>   time*, which is the calendar time expressed for some specific time zone, and with *Daylight
>   Saving Time*, which is a temporary change in the algorithm for determining local time.
>   The local time zone and Daylight Saving Time are implementation-defined.

However, the definition of "*processor time*" is missing.

Section 7.23.2.1 paragraph 2 of the C99 states:

> The `clock` function determines the processor time used.

What is "*processor time*?" Is "*processor time*" defined within the C99 standard; if so, where is it defined?

Comment: There is a SYSTICK interrupt that increments a counter, which is set to 0 on startup. The system time is the current counter value. It's used for relative not absolute time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard doesn't define the phrase "processor time". It uses it in its normal technical English sense.

The standard includes a list of normative references in section 2, one of which is:

- ISO/IEC 2382−1:1993, *Information technology — Vocabulary — Part 1: Fundamental terms.*

If that document defined "processor time", then that's the definition used by the standard.  I don't know whether it does or not, since I don't have access to that document.

But the idea is that "processor time" is the amount of type used by the CPU, which excludes time spent sleeping or waiting for some event such as the completion of an I/O request.  For example, a program that reads a line of input from the keyboard might consume, say, 60 seconds of "wall-clock time" (if the user takes that long to respond), but only a fraction of a second of processor time.  Usually elapsed processor time will be less than elapsed "wall clock" time, but it might be greater if the program runs on multiple CPUs.

Incidentally, this wording has not changed significantly across C90, C99, and C11.

Answer (score 0):

Per 7.23.1:

> The header **< time.h >** defines two macros ... **NULL** (described in 7.17);
>   and
>
> **CLOCKS_PER_SEC**
>
> which expands to a constant expression with type **clock_t** (described
>   below) that is the number per second of the value returned by the
>   **clock** function.

Therefore processor time must mean a `clock_t` value measured in `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`, given that the spec defines that as the result of a call to `clock` and elsewhere uses the term 'processor time' as the name for that result.

Comment: It seems a bit too circular to say that *processor time* is defined as a `clock_t` value measured by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` (i.e. *processor time* is the returned value of `clock` and `clock` returns *processor time*); however, this may simply be a flaw of the C99 standard that *processor time* is not better defined.

Comment: It's not circular to my mind, just oblique: the meaning of what `clock` returns is well defined by 7.23.1, 7.23.2.1 then defines that the thing returned by `clock` is known as processor time, which allows a complete interpretation of 7.31.1.